# Question about HTTP exception handling on iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, exception, connection

I try to add a method to handle exception, but the program just crashes instead of pop up an AlertView.

1) I set up the connection:

```
-(void)connect:(NSString *)strURL
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy    
                                                            timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) 
    {
        // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // inform the user that the download could not be made
    }

}
```

2)I add method to receive data and conver it to string:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // append the new data to the receivedData
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    ReturnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

3)I add exception handle method:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError: (NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle: [error localizedDescription]
                               message: [error localizedFailureReason]
                               delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

After I change the strURL to a wrong url, the program just crashes. Any ideas why the AlertView doesn't pop up?

Comment: Have you tried running through the program with the debugger?

Does your `didFailWithError` get called?

What is the error?

Comment: No, the method 'didFailWithError' didn't get called. I use a wrong url to connect so I don't understand why it was not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [error handling that I've got in this file](http://github.com/matthewmccullough/iphoneandjavawebservices/blob/21ae01c9114f3a7e9e7439465f1c2dc4ca570c64/iPhoneConsumer-REST/Classes/IPhoneWSConsumerViewController.m).  If you set the URL to an invalid URL, it does (in my example) come back with a nice dialog error message.  I just tried it to be sure.

Relevant code in the linked file is:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError: (NSError *)error {
  UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle: [error localizedDescription]
                 message: [error localizedFailureReason]
                 delegate:nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [errorAlert show];
  [errorAlert release];
  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  NSLog (@"Connection Failed with Error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I find the problem now. I should wait 60 seconds to see the alert as I set the timeout interval 60 sec.